# Convert SQL query into linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

**Convert SQL query to LINQ C#**

```
SELECT   ts.TeacherId, count(Distinct ts.SubjectId) as Subjects
from dbo.TeacherSubjects ts
GROUP BY ts.TeacherId
HAVING ts.TeacherId  = 2352
```

here is my LINQ query

```
var SubjectsGroup = db.TeacherSubjects.Where(p => p.TeacherId == 2352).Distinct().GroupBy(x => x.TeacherId);
```

Comment: Step 1: That HAVING condition should be in the WHERE clause instead.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

Comment: oka but whats the query with where clause in Linq?

Comment: Yes its LINQ to entites

Comment: I think you should google a tutorial on LINQ and figure this out for yourself (it'll be better for you in the long run) It's a really simple LINQ query, dude. Simple enough for you to learn on your own but too simple for us to do it for you.

Comment: Here is my LINQ query

 var SubjectsGroup = db.TeacherSubjects.Where(p => p.TeacherId == 2352).Distinct().GroupBy(x => x.TeacherId);

Comment: or try this one too: var subjectGroups = from p in db.TeacherSubjects
            where p.TeacherId = 2352
            group p by p.TeacherId into ts
            select new
                   {
                       TeacherId = ts.TeacherId,
                       Subjects = ts.SubjectId.Count()
                   }

Comment: @jPhizzle not working

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: First of all Thanks to all 
after spending couple of hours i finally found the solution 
Here is the LINQ Query
.
`
 var teacherSubjects = db.TeacherSubjects.Where(x => x.TeacherId == 2352).ToList();

            var grouped = teacherSubjects
                .GroupBy(x => x.TeacherId)
                .Select(group => new { teacherId = group.Key, Subjects = group.**Distinct(new SubjectIdComparer())** });`

The core part is to implement the Comparer to find the distinct elements

Comment: ** var teacherSubjects = db.TeacherSubjects.Where(x => x.TeacherId == 2352).ToList();
var grouped = teacherSubjects
.GroupBy(x => x.TeacherId)
.Select(group => new { teacherId = group.Key, Subjects = group.Distinct(new SubjectIdComparer()) });**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var teacherId = ;  // your teacherId here

var result = new {
    TeacherId = teacherId,
    Subjects = db.TeacherSubjects.Where(ts => ts.TeacherId == teacherId).Select(x => x.SubjectId).Distinct().Count()
};
```

Or you can group by `SubjectId`:

```
var teacherId = ;  // put your teacherId here
var result = 
    (from ts in TeacherSubjects.Where(x => x.TeacherId == teacherId)
    group ts by ts.SubjectId into gr
    select new 
    {       
        TeacherId = teacherId,
        Subjects = gr.Count()
    }).ToList();
```